# Solving $[(1-λ)a^{-p} +λb^{-p}]^{\frac{-1}{p}}=C$ for the variable $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I approach solving $[(1-λ)a^{-p} +λb^{-p}]^{\frac{-1}{p}}=C$ for the variable $b$

When the given answer is $$b =λ^{\frac{1}{pc^{p(1-λ)a^{-p^{\frac{-1}{p}}}}}}$$

Could someone elaborate the reasoning behind steps to reaching the above solution.
Very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typing mistake in the supposed solution **b=λ^1/p{c^p(1-λ)a^-p}^(-1/p)**

It should be : **b=λ^1/p{c^-p-(1-λ)a^-p}^(-1/p)**

[image]